# I'm confused on the usage of 'not until'

Tags: grammar

Consider:

> My life was a blur not until you came and changed everything.

Does this mean that her life was a blur, but then when he came, it wasn't any more? Or should *not* be eliminated so it will mean the way I said?

Comment: The _not_ seems indeed very weird in that sentence. As it stands, it is a strange way of saying "My life was not a blur - then you came along and it became a blur".

Comment: your example is not idiomatic

Comment: This seems like more of a learner's question; you might be interested in checking out [ell.se].

Comment: Although the comment by @oerkelens and the answer by Gary propose similar meanings, the sentence looks so ill-formed to me that I'm not convinced that it has any meaning at all.

Answer (score 6):

> My life was a blur not until you came and changed everything.

Your question:

> Does this mean that her life was a blur but then when he came, it
>   wasnt anymore? Or 'not' should be eliminated so it will mean the way I
>   said?

To express the meaning you mention, *not* should be removed:

> My life was a blur until you came and changed everything.

This means that the narrator's life was a blur, until the other person came and changed everything.

However the form you posted:

> My life was a blur not until you came and changed everything.

Is a very awkward construction, and actually means the opposite.

My life was a blur.... *but*... *not until* the other person came and changed everything.... meaning

> When you came and changed everything my life became a blur

or words of similar effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) Thanks for making me understand 

Comment: Just to add to this, "not until" **can** be used in other contexts to mean "only when".  Eg "Can I go to Tom's house?" "Not until you've done your homework".

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you use 'negative emphasis pattern'.
eg. Not until you came and changed everything was my life a blur.

Comment: Hi Aung Aung, welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately I don't think this is correct: it merely maintains the awkwardness of the original but with a different order. Your proposed wording would not be used by a fluent speaker. If you think I'm mistaken, you should [edit] your answer to cite independent support to demonstrate why this wording is suitable. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)